# RAM compatibility and recommendation

Tags: memory, compatibility

A few weeks ago, I asked a question for a graphics card recommendation, [here](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1212/graphics-card-for-heavy-gaming-game-development-graphics-design-and-video-edit/1257#1257)

---

What I'm planning to buy is:

- Processor: Intel i7 6700k,
- GPU:  2x (SLI) 980TI,
- Motherboard: ASUS Z170-A ATX

Now I need to choose the RAM, and I'm kinda confused. I know this motherboard supports up to 64GB RAM (4 slots). So I want to max it now to not have problems to deal in the future.

I know 64GB ram is a lot, and I'll probably not use it all, but its just for convenience.

I'm thinking about [this RAM](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NLZANJO)

Is this a good option? Is there any way to improve it? Will this "Temperature Sensor" cause problems?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The RAM you've selected is incompatible with the rest of your parts.  It is *ECC* (stores extra data in order to detect memory errors) *registered* (uses a special circuit to reduce the amount of power needed to drive signals) memory, while the CPU and mainboard you've selected only support regular (non-ECC, non-registered) memory.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience, but this time I think I covered everything up, will this [ram](http://www.avadirect.com/64GB-4-x-16GB-Ripjaws-V-Red-PC4-21300-DDR4-2666MHz-CL15-15-15-15-35-1-20V-SDRAM-DIMM-Non-ECC-Memory/Product/10150260) be compatible with the cpu/mobo? its non ecc, dimm, dual channel, unbuffered,

Comment: It should work.

Comment: I want to upgrade my ram. so before purchasing how can I determine whether a ram is compatible or not ? (maybe i should post question requesting comprehensive details)